# Accessing View inside the LinearLayout with code

Tags: android

I have a linearlayout how can i access view inside this layout with the help of 
programming.

Comment: Is it a dynamic view or a static one?

Comment: Which view ? Can you post your layout xml and be specific about your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the xml file you will need to give the view an id..

```
android:id="@+id/someRandomID"
```

Then within your main java file you add this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.someRandomID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, say if you have a `LineraLayout linearLayout`, and in its xml you have a `TextView` like

```
<LinearLayout [...]>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView" [...] />
</LinearLayout>
```

then you can access that `TextView` by

```
final TextView txt = (TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Here you have your LinearLayout defined in an xml resource file.
You must assign an `id` attribute to your `TextView` for that to be accessible from your code directly. For this purpose stands there the `android:id="@+id/textView"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(([TYPE]) findViewById(R.id.[NAME]))
```

For example, setting the text on a button:

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button)).setText("New text");
```

Comment: What if view is dynamic and has no id?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a linearlayout with id "linear1" and within that layout you have a ImageView with id "image1", you can do the following in your onCreate method in your activity class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
  setContentView(R.layout.linear1);

  ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
}
```

This is a very simple example, assuming that you are setting linear1 as the main layout of your activity.